# Adding a single file to a Subversion repository but not other files along the path

Tags: svn, version-control

The context is that I have an on off-the-shelf CMS which I want to make customizations to; so I want to keep the files I modify under version control, but I don't see the need to put the whole file tree under version control.

My problem is that I need to add a file to be kept under version control which is located a few subdirectories down, but I don't want to add anything else to the repository asides from the file and its parent folders.

To illustrate, say I have the following file in my project:

project/folder1/folder2/file.txt

I want to add file.txt to the repository, and folder1 is under version control but folder2 is not. There are existing files in folder1 and folder2 which I do not want to all put under version control.

Doing an `svn import folder1/folder2/file.txt` doesn't seem to work, as then I need to check out the file, and even if I delete the local version first, SVN complains that its parent folder exist. I presume that this means that if I use the --force option this would just clobber the contents of these folders.

The problem with `svn add folder1/folder2/file.txt` is that it requires each parent folder to be in the repository already (I gather from the fact that it can't find the folder2/.svn/entries file), but only folder1 is in the repository. So I figured I could do `svn add folder1/folder2` first. The problem is that this puts the entire contents of folder2 into the repository, which I don't want. It seems the solution would be to do `svn add --depth=empty folder1/folder2` which just adds the folder and no contents, but the --depth option is a new feature in Subversion 1.5, whereas I'm using 1.4.2 and it would good to avoid upgrading at this point.

So I'm wondering if there is a way around the lack of a --depth option in older versions of Subversion? Or is there another way of solving this problem" I'm also wondering if perhaps the way I went about setting it up in the first place was not so helpful.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should add the folder with the option "--non-recursive":

```
svn add --non-recursive folder1/folder2
```

Comment: I saw that option but for some reason thought it would mean add each sub item, but don't descend any further. But it did exactly what I was after, thanks :)

Answer (score 29):

If your client version is 1.5 or above, you can simply use

```
svn add --parents folder1/folder2/file.txt
```

to have the file and its parent directories added.

Comment: This answer deserves more attention.  These days, this is a _much_ faster solution than the other answers.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use the quick version, "-N", which is the short form of "--non-recursive", as in

`svn add -N folder1/folder2`